# Nodemailer, connection times out

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I' m using the nodemailer, https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer.

I tried with the example (with changed emails ofcourse). It's not working. Nothing get consoled out. After 30-40s I get:

```
{ [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT' }
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Any hint on what can be wrong? How do I debug?

Here's the code from the example. I pasted this into the server.js, so it fires when the app starts.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});

// NB! No need to recreate the transporter object. You can use
// the same transporter object for all e-mails

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ✔', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

**Update**
Turns out, my company has blocked googles smtp. So there was nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: A timeout usually means that the server doesn't respond.

Comment: Can you paste your code in jsbin so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: @V31 Actually code should always be included in the question itself, too.

Comment: Code is now included.

Comment: It is not able to connect to the Google servers. Also, what version are you using of nodemailer?

Comment: @majidarif, if this is the case, shouldn't this be printed in the console?

Comment: Tested the exact code and it works for me. So there must be something wrong with your connection to the google smtp servers.

Comment: Also tried with a yahoo mail. No luck. Very mysterious.

Comment: Can I set a timeout for a connection? I know the server I'm trying to connect to isn't available (trying to test when chaos happens) but nginx times out before nodemailer does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ix with Gmail. If you change to another email, it will work :)